# Trying to rebuild a 2 disk RAID0 array, superblock overwritten, but backup superblocks look good

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I have two hitachi 1TB hard drives that were 2TB of storage in a D-link DNS323 NAS appliance. The NAS device sat in storage for a couple of years. When I fired it up the D-link NAS reported no array. I tried to recreate the RAID device using the appliance "tools". but all that did was create a new RAID0 array as if I had just inserted 2 new hard drives. I used MDADM to try and reassemeble the array and that also ended up with an empty 2 TB array. Before the array went into storage, it was almost full with nearly 1.8 TB of photos and video.

I used testdisk to scan the  array and it found several superblocks for the correct size of and date of the array I originally had across the two hard drives:

recover_EXT2:s_block_group_nr=0/14864, s_mnt_count=12/38, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192

recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count= 487066656
recover_EXT2: part_size 3896533248
Filesystem created: Mon Jul 6 00:18:24 2015
Last Mount time: Wed Jan 4 15:50:12 2023

P ext2 0 0 1 487066655 1 4 3896533248
ext2 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 1995 GB / 1858 GB

recover_EXT2: part_offset problem

What's the best way to try and recreate this array and hopefully recover some data? Can I use MDADM and just point it to a backup superblock as the man page suggests? I know which disk holds the partition table, but might that have changed when either the D-link or MDADM reassemble attempts happened?

should I go with one of the two testdisk recommendations of "try e2fsck -b 32768 (or one of the other back up superblocks test disk found) -B 4096 device"

or

echo "0 3896533248 linear /dev/md127 0" | dmsetup create test0

if the latter, how do I mount the two array members in their specific order and as read only so I can mount the two disks as md127?